# Does p4 sync also verify the local files?

Tags: perforce

I'm writing a build script that creates a workspace and syncs the workspace to download all of the files in a specific depot.  I want to verify the downloaded files, or at least make sure they are verified somewhere along the way.

I'm already running p4 sync to download the files, but does p4 sync also verify them/check them against their checksum?  Would it be redundant for me to verify them after p4 sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing `p4 sync` does is comparing the file revision (the number after the `#` in the filename given by Perforce clients) in the workspace and in the depot. The revision from the depot is then downloaded into the workspace if it is newer than the workspace one.

As far as I know, there is no checksumming anywhere when it comes to verifying files (or their revisions) in Perforce. If you want to do it this way, you'll have to manually run a checksum function on the workspace file and the depot file (which you'd need to download separately into a temporary directory), but doing it like this will defeat the purpose of the whole procedure.

Comment: An answer to this question: [Verify Perforce client file copies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7129906/1405720) seems to indicate that the checksumming is possible with p4 diff.  However, the first paragraph of your answer answers my original question.

Comment: Actually, 'p4 sync' **does** verify the checksum for any file it transfers from the server. This was added 4 years ago, in version 2010.2. This only applies to the files that sync actually transfers; the files that are already up-to-date on your workstation are not re-verified. The purpose of the checksum verification is to detect damage (or sabotage) of the network or the server itself, and so it's quite useful.

Comment: @BryanPendleton : Would you mind providing some documentation on that? I'd like to update the answer.

Comment: One place where this behavior is documented is in the server release notes (ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/doc/user/relnotes.txt). Search for 'Bug #1291' or '259157' and you will see the release note I mean. Not much doc, sorry, but better than nothing :)